# Why the tables content is not updated if the aws database connection is successfull

Tags: aws-lambda

I launched my database in EC2 and my web-service is running locally.

The cloud-watch shows a successful database connection. But the table content information is not able to retrieve properly and it doesn't show any error message.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello welcome to SO. Do you have like a log of what is going on or some sample codes we can look?

Comment: Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect database from local machine with native database tool and run the sql to check if you can see the content of the table in sql prompt or how fast the data can fetch.

Thank - Tarun